# Mybatis : "less than" issue in Select annotations

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I am using java7, spring 3 and mybatis

**Pom.xml**

```
<org.mybatis-version>3.2.8</org.mybatis-version>
<org.mybatis-spring-version>1.2.2</org.mybatis-spring-version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
    <version>${org.mybatis-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${org.mybatis-spring-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

While using annotation based Select i came across with strange issue where below mentioned code was throwing exception due to use of < (Less then) while > (greater then) works as expected.

```
<script>
SELECT * FROM STUDENT
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = #{depId}
<if test='joiningDate != null'> AND STUDENT_ID <= #{joiningDate} </if>
</script>
```

After googling for a while i find out this issue reported below.

https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=787

Above issue can be fixed by replacing < (less then) with `&lt;` as shown below.

```
<script>
SELECT * FROM STUDENT
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = #{depId}
<if test='joiningDate != null'> AND STUDENT_ID &lt;= #{joiningDate} </if>
</script>
```

I have also came across of suggestion for using  using CDATA or ^ in respected scenarios which i haven't given try yet.

**Question:**

- My question is shouldn't this issue be fixed by Mybatis team (at-least xml specific conversion for frequently used query tags) or this behaviour is as expected since we are using `<script>` tag ??
- Is there any alternate solution which i have missed out ?

Comment: when you replace with &lt; , what error occurs?

Comment: Its works perfectly as mentioned in above but my question is isn't this a work around then actual fix ? or is there fix i am not aware of then using &lt; ?

Comment: That is the only solution. In XML file , always we have to use ascii values as &lt; &amp; etc etc. For Mybatis, there wont be any exception to this rule.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To be fair, it's not the issue in `MyBatis`, but the behaviour of XML parsing.

If you don't want characters such as `<` and `&` to be parsed, you can use the term `CDATA` to prevent the XML parser to parse such text. Please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp for detail. Or you may escape it with `&lt` as comments.

I.E.

```
<script>
SELECT * FROM STUDENT
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = #{depId}
<if test='joiningDate != null'> 
<![CDATA[
AND STUDENT_ID <= #{joiningDate} 
]]>
</if>
</script>
```

Comment: Yep .... I also believe CDATA is better choice as mentioned in my comment one of the option.  Though I was just hoping if this could have taken care by Mybatis internally. As unlike other XML parser this one meant for query which is kinda predictable that user will face this issue.  At least a not if not much to expect :P

Comment: I don't think it's a good way to handle it in MyBatis. There're still some tags such as `<if>`, `<foreach>`, etc needed to be parsed inside `<script>`, and there could be more for the time being. It's not efficient and extensible to change the common xml parsing behaviour.

Comment: I didn't meant to change the XML behaviour but to either add by default cdata tags or HTML encode the character similar to "less then"

Answer (score -2):

you too can use that.

<= less or equal
    
    SELECT * FROM STUDENT
    WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = #{depId}

> = greater that

```
<script>
SELECT * FROM STUDENT
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = #{depId}
<if test='joiningDate != null'> 
<![CDATA[
AND STUDENT_ID &gt;= #{joiningDate} 
]]>
</if>
</script>
```

Comment: You can do `<![CDATA[]]>`, or `&gt;=`, but not both.