# Exception with rownum in mybatis

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

Following is my sql query that is used in mybatis mapper xml.

```
<select id="getData"   fetchSize="30" resultType="java.util.HashMap" >
            select * from table
            where module='AB'
            and rownum < 15
</select>
```

I am getting below exception while using rownum :

```
 Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 130; columnNumber: 16; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

Below things I have tried:

```
ROWNUM&lt;=15  AND <![CDATA[ ROWNUM <= 15 ]]>
```

But still it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select id="getData" fetchSize="30" resultType="java.util.HashMap" >
            select * from table
            where module='AB'
            <![CDATA[ AND ROWNUM <= 15 ]]>
</select>
```

or  `ROWNUM &lt;= 15` (with whitespaces after `ROWNUM` and before 15).

Comment: The query that I use is `select eq_id as id, area as eq_area, status,job_no, 
            PLAN_START_TIME, PLAN_END_TIME, CREATE_DATE as systime ,
   ESTIMATED_END_TIME from tab_data
   where module='BB' <![CDATA[ AND ROWNUM <= 15 ]]>` but it is still failing is there any where else in xml that needs similar treatment as simply `select * from tab_data` is giving me results succesfully so there is nothing wrong in code but I think something is wrong in sql written inside mapper.xml

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: Oracle . But thanks it works now there was conflict due to date format which I fixed and rownum works perfectly as per your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have tried the `&lt;` or the `<![CDATA[ ]]>`  on all the right places? (seems it's a large(r) file with perhaps multiple errors).

Since the code example you give is without the `=` and in the things you tried you add an `=`. And your error is on line 130 column 16 of your file, and we only see 5 lines and the `<` does not seem to be in column 16.

You could try to use: http://www.validome.org/xml/ and see if the entire configuration file is valid?

You can also read more about this on another question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29136039/244748